# SQLAlchemy: Difficulty Querying my DB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a small Python script / app and am just getting my feet wet with SQLAlchemy.  The only class I have is "Player", which is defined as follows:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,  rating, college, ranking = None, firstName = None, lastName = None):
        self.rating = rating
        self.college = college
        self.ranking = ranking
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
```

Now I have a module called databaseFunctions.py and within it I have these two functions:

```
#if player exists, update his rating and ranking; otherwise, add new object to DB
def updateSpecificDBEntry(playerObject, session):
    #find player in DB with firstName and lastName
    currentPlayer = session.query(Player).filter(firstName == playerObject.firstName).filter(playerObject.lastName == lastName).first()
    #set rating = newRating
    if currentPlayer.count():
        currentPlayer.rating = playerObject.rating
        currentPlayer.ranking = playerObject.ranking
    else:
        addEntryToDB(playerObject, session)

def updateEntireDB(arrayOfPlayerObjects, session):
    for player in arrayOfPlayerObjects:
        updateSpecificDBEntry(player, session)
```

Here's what my main method looks like:

```
def main():
    #create engine (for use by base and session)
    engine = databaseFunctions.createEngine()
    #create session
    session = databaseFunctions.createSession(engine)
    #get all players from CSA website
    allPlayers = getSortedGender(constants.mainURL, constants.menTeams)
    databaseFunctions.updateEntireDB(allPlayers, session)
```

My code actually works up until the last function call.  At this point, I get the following error:

```
  File "helpfulFunctions.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "helpfulFunctions.py", line 107, in main
    databaseFunctions.updateEntireDB(allPlayers, session)
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/databaseFunctions.py", line 42, in updateEntireDB
    updateSpecificDBEntry(player, session)
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/databaseFunctions.py", line 32, in updateSpecificDBEntry
    currentPlayer = session.query(Player).filter(firstName == playerObject.firstName).filter(playerObject.lastName == lastName).first()
NameError: global name 'firstName' is not defined
```

I'm a bit confused because I'm querying all Player objects in the DB for entries whose first names match the `firstName` of the passed in `playerObject` and whose last names match the `lastName` of the passed in `playerObject`.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

I initially called this function in main() but wasn't using it so took it out:

```
def createBase(engine):  
    Base = declarative_base()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return Base
```

As in, I was saying:

```
Base = databaseFunctions.createBase(engine)
```

And then doing nothing with `Base`.  Not sure if this is part of the issue.

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updateSpecificDBEntry filter, you have:

`.filter(firstName == playerObject.firstName)`

The variable "firstName" doesn't exist.

It looks like you meant something like:

`currentPlayer = session.query(Player).filter(Player.firstName == playerObject.firstName).filter(playerObject.lastName == Player.lastName).first()`

So you're filtering a Player column, against the given playerObject attribute.